# createUser is not a function error while wriiting unit test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am getting below error while writing unit test case of my function.

```
(0 , _service.createUser) is not a function

TypeError: (0 , _service.createUser) is not a function
    at _callee$ (https://pbz00.csb.app/src/service.test.js:43:44)
    at tryCatch (https://pbz00.csb.app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (https://pbz00.csb.app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:288:22)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (https://pbz00.csb.app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
```

**here is my function**

```
export const createUser = async values => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post("http:/10.13.15.245:3000/create", {
      values
    });
    console.log("response", response);
    if (response && response.data && response.data.status.code === "200") {
      abc = true;
      return abc;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.response && e.response.data) {
      console.log(e.response.data.message);
    }
  }
};
```

I want to check it's return value `true` or `undefined`.

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-galois-pbz00

```
import { createUser } from "./service.test";

describe("service test", () => {
  it("check abc value", async () => {
    const axios = {
      post: jest.fn(() =>
        Promise.resolve({
          data: {
            greeting: "hello there",
            status: {
              code: "200"
            }
          }
        })
      )
    };
    console.log("createUser", createUser);
    let abc = await createUser();
    console.log("after createUser", abc);
    expect(abc).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

[image]

```
import { createUser } from "./service";

describe("service test", () => {
  it("check abc value", async () => {
    jest.spyOn(axios, "post").mockImplementation(() =>
      Promise.resolve({
        data: {
          greeting: "hello there",
          status: {
            code: "200"
          }
        }
      })
    );
    console.log("createUser", createUser);
    let abc = await createUser();
    console.log("after createUser", abc);
    expect(abc).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

**updated**

```
import { createUser } from "./service";
import axios from "axios";
describe("service test", () => {
  it("check abc value", async () => {
    jest.spyOn(axios, "post").mockImplementation(() =>
      Promise.resolve({
        data: {
          greeting: "hello there",
          status: {
            code: "200"
          }
        }
      })
    );
    console.log("createUser", createUser);
    let abc = await createUser();
    console.log("after createUser", abc);
    expect(abc).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing it wrong. It should be:

```js
import { createUser } from "./service";
```

to mock `axios` module, you can use this:

```
jest
  .spyOn(axios, 'post')
  .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({
     data: {
       greeting: "hello there",
       status: {
        code: "200"
       }
     }
  }))
```

You could also mock the whole module: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html#mocking-modules

Comment: but it is not returing true or false ..how to mock my request ?

Comment: do you have any idea how to check `abc` variable value or returning value ?

Comment: This can answer your question: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html#mocking-modules

Comment: thanks for answering..!! see update.now axios is not found

Comment: update code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-galois-pbz00

Comment: `Could not find dependency: 'axios' relative to '/src/service.js'`

Comment: You need to add `axios` to your project dependencies.

Comment: I already installed axios in my project ..will i import that in my test file ?

Comment: I already install `axios` package and also include in `service and test file` still same error

Comment: still getting same error ..https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-galois-pbz00